What is the dual space of $C^1_0(\Omega)$ for open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?
What is the dual space of $C^1_0(\Omega)$ for open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\Omega$ is an open, possibly unbounded set, and $C^1_0(\Omega)$ is equipped with the supremum norm $\|f\|:=\sup_{\Omega} |f| + |\nabla f|$?
Barozzi, Gonzalez and Massari's 'The mean curvature of a Lipschitz continuous manifold' p.258 applies the Riesz representation theorem in a way that suggests it consists of operators $L(f)$ given by $L(f):=\sum_{i=1}^k \int_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} d\mathbf{H}_i$, where each $\mathbf{H}_i$ is a Radon measure on $\Omega$. Why is this correct?

The key fact of the proof is the duality  $(C^0_0(\Omega))^\ast\simeq\mathcal M_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ (not $BV(\Omega)$ but indeed the space of its generalized derivatives), as already guessed: what is needed is more detail on the steps involved in the use of this fact. Precisely, we should

recall first how the topologies on $C^1_0(\Omega)$ and on $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$ are defined, then
show that there exist an embedding $\nu$ between those two topological vector spaces then, by using the Hahn-Banach theorem, extend all linear functionals on $\nu(C^1_0(\Omega))$ to functionals defined the whole space $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$, in order to characterise the dual space of the former by using what is know on the dual space of the latter and finally
determine a representation theorem for linear functionals in $(C_0^1(\Omega))^\ast$ as a consequence of the structure of $(C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1}))^\ast$ and of the standard representation theorem $(C^0_0(\Omega))^\ast\simeq\mathcal M_\text{loc}(\Omega)$.

Why it is necessary to proceed in such a complex way? Because in principle you cannot expect that a functional defined on a subspace could be extended to the whole function space (think for example of analytic functionals or even distributions), so you have to prove it following al the steps involved, the ones described above in this case.
Step 1: topologies on $C^1_0(\Omega)$ and $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$.
It is standard fact from functional analysis that $C^1_0(\Omega)$ is a Frechet space (unless $\Omega$ is compact, for in that case it is a Banach space). This means that the topology on this space is defined by a countable set of seminorms, for example the following ones
$$
p_{ Q_j}^1(f) = \sup_{x\in Q_j} |f(x)| + \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{x\in Q_j} \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial{x_i}}(x)\right|\quad\forall f\in C^1_0(\Omega)\label{s1}\tag{$\mathscr{s}_1$}
$$
where the $Q_j$, for all ${j\in\Bbb N_{>0}}\subseteq\Omega$ are compact sets such that their family $\{Q_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N_{>0}}$ is a covering of $\Omega$ such that $Q_j\cap Q_k\subsetneq\partial Q_j\cap\partial Q_k$ if $j\neq k$. These seminorms give rise to a metric on $C^1_0(\Omega)$, for example
$$
d_1(f,g)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{p_{ Q_j}^1(f-g)}{1 + p_{ Q_j}^1(f-g)}\quad\forall f,g\in C^1_0(\Omega).\label{d1}\tag{$\mathscr{d}_1$}
$$
In an analogous way we see that also $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$ is a Frechet space whose topology is given by the seminorms
$$
p_{ Q_j}^0(v) = \sum_{i=0}^n \sup_{x\in Q_j} \left|v_i(x)\right| = \sup_{x\in Q_j} |v_0(x)| + \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{x\in Q_j} \left|v_i(x)\right| \quad \forall v\in C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})
\label{s0}\tag{$\mathscr{s}_0$}
$$
where the family $\{Q_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N_{>0}}$ is the same described above. The metric defined by these seminorms is given by
$$
d_0(v,w)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{p_{ Q_j}^1(v-w)}{1 + p_{ Q_j}^1(v-w)}\quad\forall v, w\in C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1}). \label{d0}\tag{$\mathscr{d}_0$}
$$
Step 2: the map $\nu:C^1_0(\Omega)\to C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$, its metric properties and their consequences.
Let's now define a linear map $\nu$ between vector spaces as
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\nu:C^1_0(\Omega)& \to & C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1}) \\
f & \mapsto &(f,\nabla f) 
\end{array}
$$
where $(f,\nabla f)\simeq\left (f, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right)$.
The image $\nu( C^1_0(\Omega)) = \big \{\nu(f)\mid f\in C_0^1(\Omega) \big\}$ is evidently a linear vector subspace of $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$, and $\nu$ is evidently an injective map: moreover, since
$$
p_{ Q_j}^1(f)=p_{ Q_j}^1(\nu (f))\quad \forall f\in C^1_0(\Omega) \land \forall j\in \Bbb N_{>0}
$$
the topology induced by the metric \eqref{d1} on $C^1_0(\Omega)$ is the same induced on $\nu( C^1_0(\Omega))$ by the metric \eqref{d0}, therefore $\nu$ is an embedding.
Now consider a continuous linear functional ${L} \in (\nu( C^1_0(\Omega)))^\ast$: it is a standard fact from functional analysis that, since $\nu( C^1_0(\Omega))$ is a Frechet space and thus a seminormed space then $L$ is a bounded operator (see for example [1], chapter 1, §1.5, pp. 21-22, theorem 2) i.e. there exists a positive constant $M_{p^0_{Q_j}}>0$ such that, for the $j$-th seminorm of the \eqref{s0} family the following inequality holds:
$$
\lvert L(v)\rvert \le M_{p^0_{Q_j}}p^0_{Q_j}(v) \quad \forall v\in \nu( C^1_0(\Omega)).
$$
As a consequence, by invoking the Hahn-Banach theorem we can extend $L$ to a functional $\tilde L\in (C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1}))^\ast$ such that
$$
L(v)=\tilde L(v)\quad \forall v\in \nu( C^1_0(\Omega))^\ast.
$$
For the sake of simplicity and by abuse of notation, in the last point we'll use $L$ instead of $\tilde L$.
Step 3: the structure of linear continuous functionals on $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})$ and its consequences.
Since $C_0^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^{n+1})\simeq \underbrace{C_0^0(\Omega)\times\cdots\times C_0^0(\Omega)}_{n+1}$, by a standard theorem in functional analysis
$$
\left( V_1\times \cdots\times V_m\right)^\ast\simeq \bigoplus_{k=1}^{m}(V_k)^\ast
$$ meaning with this that
$$
L(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} L_i(x_i).
$$ But then we are done since this, jointly with the fact that $(C^0_0(\Omega))^\ast\simeq\mathcal M_\text{loc}(\Omega)$, directly implies that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{d\!}
L(f) \simeq L(\nu(f)) = \int_\Omega f \Dm\mathbf{H}_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Dm\mathbf{H}_i 
\quad \forall f\in C_0^1(\Omega)\land L\in(C_0^1(\Omega))^\ast
$$
where $\mathbf H_i$, $i= 0, 1,\ldots, n$ are Radon measures, i.e. $\mathbf H_i\in\mathcal M_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ for all $i= 0, 1,\ldots, n$.
Notes

Maybe the use of the property of seminormed spaces used in step 2 is somewhat an overkill, put it was the cleanest way I found to be able to apply the Hahn-Banach

The above proof is not easily found in textbooks or monograph: to my knowledge, the unique reference that explains how to prove such kind of result is the beautiful book (not a textbook nor a specialised monograph, according to his Author) [2] by Carlo Miranda (see §54, pp. 334-335 end the paragraphs cited therein). Miranda deals with the case  $C^r(\Omega)$, $r\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ (yes, no hypothesis of compactness of support required) and also with the case when $\Omega$ is bounded and satisfies the cone property.


References
[1] Alexandre Grothendieck, Topological vector spaces, Translated from the French by Orlando Chaljub, 3 ed. (English)
Notes on Mathematics and Its Applications. Philadelphia, PA: Gordon and Breach Science Publishers, pp. xi+245 (1992), MR0372565, Zbl 0763.46002.
[2] Carlo Miranda, Istituzioni di analisi funzionale lineare. Volume I (Foundations of linear functional analysis. Volume I), (Italian) Unione Matematica Italiana. Bologna: Pitagora Editrice, pp. iii+596 (1978), Zbl 0697.46001.
Carlo Miranda, Istituzioni di analisi funzionale lineare. Volume II. (Foundations of linear functional analysis. Volume II), (Italian) Unione Matematica Italiana. Bologna: Pitagora Editrice. pp. 597-748 (1979), Zbl 0697.46002.

My understanding so far is as follows. I will improve it when I have time and understand it better.
The dual space of $C^0_0(\Omega)$ is $BV(\Omega)$, the space of functions of bounded variation on $\Omega$. Note that all the first derivatives of $f$ are $C^0_0(\Omega)$ functions. So part of me would expect the answer to consist of operators $L(f):=\int_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} d\mathbf{H}_i + \int_\Omega f d\mathbf{H}_0$. But we can express the value of $f$ at any point as an integral of its first derivatives, since it is zero outside a compact subset of $\Omega$. Thus, we can put the $\mathbf{H}_0$ inside the other $\mathbf{H}_i$, and obtain the expression from Barozzi et al.
